# How to begin a multiplepage ToC on the left and to insert blank pages around it

Tags: table-of-contents, blank-page

I use this the `article` class (I prefer to stick to this one for compatibility), in twoside mode with a toc taking two pages (but it would be better if the code copes with an arbitrary number of pages). I want to have

- the title page (page style empty)
- blank page  (page style empty)
- the summary (page style empty)
- the acknowledgement (page style empty) (I do not want the acknowledgement on the same page as the summary, but only on the recto)
- the blank page (page style empty)(I do not want the acknowledgement facing the toc)
- the toc p1 (page style empty)
- the toc p2 (page style empty)
- blank page(s) (page style empty) in order to make the first section start on the left, and such that the first page of the first section is not the recto of the last page of the ToC
- the first section

Normally, the toc begins on a left page (in book view) but my MWE shows it does not. I attempt to introduce blank pages but `\newpage` is not effective.

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\small
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}
                {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}
\thispagestyle{empty}
}%
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{title}
Title
\end{title}

\cleardoublepage
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\clearpage
%\newpage


\newenvironment{mysum}
{
%\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\vfill
\begin{center}
\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape\selectfont Summary\end{center}
}
{\vfill\null}
\begin{mysum}
My summary.
\end{mysum}


\clearpage

\newenvironment{myack}
{
%\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\vfill
\begin{center}
\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape\selectfont Acknowledgements\end{center}
}
{\vfill\null}
\begin{myack}
\begin{center}
We thank you.
\end{center}
\end{myack}

\cleardoublepage
\newpage


\tableofcontents


\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\normalfont
\normalsize










\section{first section}

\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{first subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the first section}

\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\section{second section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{second subsection of the second section}

\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{third subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-11]


\section{third section}
%\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]


\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]








\section{first section}

\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]


\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]




\section{third section}
%\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]


\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]



\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]


\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]




\section{first section}

\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{first subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the first section}

\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]



\section{second section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{second subsection of the second section}

\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{third subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-11]


\section{third section}
%\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{second subsection of the third section}

\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]








\section{first section}

\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{first subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the first section}

\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\section{second section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{second subsection of the second section}

\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{third subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The lines `\pagenumbering{arabic} \normalfont \normalsize` are superflous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need a macro like

```
\newcommand{\emptypage}{\clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}
```

It will insert an empty page as the name and the definition suggests. In the solution it will be used both for adding a blank page after the titlepage and to force the ToC to the left page. (If `\emptypage` follows a `\cleardoublepage` the following content will automatically appear on the left page.)

Moreover the solution uses a simple shipout trick (with the `everyshi` package) to get all the pages 'empty' in the "frontmatter" - which technically speaking does not exist for the `article` class. Necessarily, you need to tell LaTeX where the frontmatter ends, i.e. the mainmatter starts. The solution therefore provides `\StartMainmatter` as an analogue of `\mainmatter` from the `book` class.

Also note the subtle changes to your custom environments. I applied them primarily to get a more compact code in your document body.

### Complete Solution

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{everyshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\emptypage}{\clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}
\newenvironment{myack}
  {\null\thispagestyle{empty} \vfill
  \begin{center}
    \rmfamily\bfseries\scshape Acknowledgements
  \end{center}
  \begin{center}}%
  {\vfill\null
  \end{center}
  \cleardoublepage}
\newenvironment{mysum}
  {\null\thispagestyle{empty} \vfill
  \begin{center}
    \rmfamily\bfseries\scshape Summary
  \end{center}}%
  {\vfill\null \clearpage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \small
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}
                {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}
  \thispagestyle{empty}}%

\newif\if@mainmatter %\mainmatterfalse
\newcommand{\StartMainmatter}{\@mainmattertrue \thispagestyle{plain}}
\EveryShipout{\if@mainmatter\else\thispagestyle{empty}\fi} %'empty' pagestyle in the frontmatterpages that are created through \clearpage, etc.
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \null\thispagestyle{empty}
  Title
\end{titlepage}

\emptypage

\begin{mysum}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{mysum}

\begin{myack}
  We thank you.
\end{myack}

\emptypage
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\StartMainmatter

\section{first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{first subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\section{second section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{third subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\section{third section}
%\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\section{first section}
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\section{third section}
%\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\section{first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{first subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-22]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\section{second section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{third subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\section{third section}
%\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{first subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the third section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\section{first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{first subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{third subsection of the first section}
\lipsum[1-11]

\section{second section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{first subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{second subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\subsection{third subsection of the second section}
\lipsum[1-11]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The \emptypage seems to do what matters without the everyshi approach (but what is the \null command ?) What is the front matter you are evoking ?

Comment: @Phillip the `everyshi` thing secures that pages in the output created by `\clear(double)page` are also empty. `\null` is just an empty `\hbox`. I used it in the definition of `\emptypage` to make sure that `\thispagestyle{empty}` will effect the right page.